# How to add the unavailable word to One drive Word file dictionary

Tags: ms-word, onedrive

When I'm writing the notes in **OneDrive Word Files**, some words might be not available in the dictionary. So, it is showing ***red/blue squiggly*** under the words.

For offline word application, we have the option to add new words in the dictionary.
But for online word application, only **`ignore`** option I can see but I have to click ignore for the same word repeated n number of times and I can't see "**`Ignore All`**" or "**`Add to Dictionary`**" for adding the unavailable word to **OneDrive Word** Application Dictionary.

[image]

[image]

**How to add the unavailable words in OneDrive Word File Application Dictionary**?

Comment: This is NOT a spelling correction.  It's NOT a missing word, so you can't patch it.  It is a grammar warning, because the phrase "compute resources" is not an accepted usage in the general language.  "Compute" is a verb, not a adjective.  You can either ignore the warning, or try something like "computing resources".

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts But Not every time I can use the word `computing` in the place of `compute` because the next word changes after compute word based on the sentence. Any other alternative?

Comment: Alternative to what?  If you have grammar problems, then you fix them, one by one.  You can't just do a global search and replace.

Comment: Alternative means what you said in the last point - Adding the word to dictionary globally  within the file or ignore all option available if by any chance. One by one fixing is a difficult task I feel

Comment: *One by one fixing is a difficult task I feel* -- That's ALWAYS how you do proofreading and grammar correction.  You have to look at every instance, because the grammar corrector is not always correct.  The alternative is just to ignore the suggestions, of course.